# The variable is empty even if you write something

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I try to generate a password, even if you enter the length Python says that the variable `lengthstr` is empty.

This is the error that Python gives me:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/salvatore/Python Projects/Password Saver/Ps.py", line 35, in <lambda>
    generatebutton = tk.Button(window, text="Genera", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), bg="#007acc", activebackground="#66c2ff", command=lambda: generate(int(lengthstr)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is my code:

```
def generate(length):
    return length
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&£*()?"
    passgen = "".join(choice(chars) for x in range(length))
    passwd = tk.Entry(window)
    passwd.insert(0, passgen)
    passwd.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="N")

def generatepassword():
    generatefunction.destroy()
    seepassbutton.destroy()
    text.destroy()

    textgen = "Genera una Password"
    textgen = tk.Label(window, text=textgen, fg="#333333", font=("Helvetica", 32, "bold"))
    textgen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N")

    length = tk.Entry(window, justify="center")
    length.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, ipadx=42)
    lengthstr = length.get()
    print(lengthstr)

    textgen = "Inserisci la lunghezza della Password"
    textgen = tk.Label(window, text=textgen, fg="#333333", font=("Helvetica", 10))
    textgen.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="N")

    generatebutton = tk.Button(window, text="Genera", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), bg="#007acc", activebackground="#66c2ff", command=lambda: generate(int(lengthstr)))
    generatebutton.config(relief="flat")
    generatebutton.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=6, ipady=1, ipadx=240)
```

Comment: Please visit and read https://stackoverflow.com/help
Also provide a minimal working example. Your code is to complex.

Comment: You created an Entry, and then *immediately* called `.get()` on it.  You received an empty string, of course - where are you imagining that any other value could have possibly come from?  You need to do the `.get()` in the Button's `command=` function, which presumably won't happen until after the user has typed something in.

Comment: what exactly does `lengthstr` return

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Comment: @IsaacFrank I think it's the length of the password the user requests, but I could be wrong...

Comment: Also, when you run this `def generate(length): return length` it will not execute any more code in that function.

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Exactly, it returns length before any logic is being done.

Comment: Yes @IsaacFrank but then what happens to `passgen = "".join(choice(chars) for x in range(length))
    passwd = tk.Entry(window)
    passwd.insert(0, passgen)
    passwd.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="N")`?

Comment: It doesn't run..

Answer (score 2):

```
def generate(length):
    #This `return length` won't let your logic in this function run
    return length
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&£*()?"
    passgen = "".join(choice(chars) for x in range(length))
    passwd = tk.Entry(window)
    passwd.insert(0, passgen)
    passwd.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="N")
```

But the error is from command of your button

```
generatebutton = tk.Button(window, ...., command=lambda: generate(int(lengthstr)))
```

You are trying to convert an invalid literal to an int, what is the value of lengthstr? if it is a float literal e.g '1.5' you have to convert to float before converting to int like so:

```
 generatebutton = tk.Button(window, ..., command=lambda:generate(int(float(lengthstr)))
```

## EDIT:

I found your `lengthstr` variable, at the time where you did this `lengthstr = length.get()` the entry will be `''` which is an empty string and can't be converted to an Int..

Move `lengthstr = length.get()` into the generate function so your Button only gets the Entry field once the user clicks the button, and then you can convert to an int..

Remove the function parameter, then in the command, just call the function.

Comment: You are right indeed, I think the value for `lengthstr` is string of `""` that is why it is giving an `ValueError: ... int() with base 10: ''` error.

Comment: Yea.. OP is trying to get the Entry field at initialization when User hasn't entered any text.

Comment: The fix is simple one can pass `lengthstr` without converting to `float` or `int` and then in `generate` function the value of `lengthstr` can be checked with some simple `if-else` statements.

Comment: Yea, or  better still get the Entry in the generate Method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is likely because you have entered nothing into the `Entry()`. To avoid this error, use a `try` and `except`.

This would be the creation of the button:

```py
try:
    generatebutton = tk.Button(window, text="Genera", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), bg="#007acc", activebackground="#66c2ff", command=lambda: generate(int(lengthstr)))
except (ValueError, NameError):
    pass

generatebutton.config(relief="flat")
generatebutton.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=6, ipady=1, ipadx=240)
```

Comment: To avoid this error they should have a button which gets it. If the program uses this code, immediately when the `Entry` is rendered,  it will try this — and if there's nothing in the `Entry`...well, it won't get the value, and they'll get `NameError`s if they try to use it.

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Fixed.

Comment: You can have a list of errors to save space eg: `except (ValueError, NameError):`. Also, I think if-else should do the trick as well by check if the entry box is empty or not.

Comment: @Saad Thank you! I did not know this.

Comment: @10Rep I meant, you are using `except: pass` instead of trying again until there _is_ no error... if this was in a loop or there was a button like the user clicked (like in my answer), it would be good. If you do it this way (only trying once, to try multiple times do your code in a while loop and if it is success (no exceptions) run `break`), and the `Entry` was empty...they'd get the error they were getting all along — converting a string (`''`) into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you need to call `.get()` **ONLY** when the user has entered in the text; for this purpose I suggest using a Button:

```py
def getTextFromEntry(theEntry):
    global lengthstr
    lengthstr = length.get()
    print(lengthstr)

def generatepassword():
    generatefunction.destroy()
    seepassbutton.destroy()
    text.destroy()

    textgen = "Genera una Password"
    textgen = tk.Label(window, text=textgen, fg="#333333", font=("Helvetica", 32, "bold"))
    textgen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N")

    length = tk.Entry(window, justify="center")
    length.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, ipadx=42)
    getValue = Button(text="Generate password", command=getTextFromEntry)
    getValue.pack()
    textgen = "Inserisci la lunghezza della Password"
    textgen = tk.Label(window, text=textgen, fg="#333333", font=("Helvetica", 10))
    textgen.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="N")

    generatebutton = tk.Button(window, text="Genera", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), bg="#007acc", activebackground="#66c2ff", command=lambda: generate(int(lengthstr)))
    generatebutton.config(relief="flat")
    generatebutton.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=6, ipady=1, ipadx=240)
```

(I'm sure there's an easier way to do this using `lambda`s, but this is the best I can do ;)

You can also try using `try` and `except` statements (like @10Rep's answer but with getting the value (`.get()`) and the conversion to `int` in a loop, and stopping the loop when successful.